# Flask preventing PUT, DELETE, and POST

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to test a Flask script I have written, by adding, amending, and deleting information. However, if I run anything other than `methods=["GET"]`, I get an error saying that the method is not allowed.

The script I am running is:

```py
#!flask/bin/python

from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, abort, make_response
from flask_cors import CORS
import csv

stocks = [
    {"id": 1, "Stock": "BoI", "Price": 300},
    {"id": 2, "Stock": "Apple", "Price": 499}
    ]

Next_ID = len(stocks)

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path="", static_folder=".")
CORS(app, support_credentials=True)

@app.route("/")

@app.route("/Stocks")
def getAll():
    return jsonify(stocks)
    # curl http://127.0.0.1:5000

@app.route("/Stocks/<int:id>")
def getById(id):
    sel_stock = list(filter(lambda s: s["id"] == id, stocks))
    if len(sel_stock) == 0:
        return jsonify ({}), 204
    else:
        return jsonify(sel_stock[0])
    # curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/1

@app.route("/Stocks", methods=["POST"])
def create(id):
    global Next_ID
    if not request.json:
        abort(400)

    stock = {
        "id": Next_ID,
        "Stock": request.json["Stock"],
        "Price": request.json["Price"],
    }
    Next_ID += 1
    stocks.append(stock)
    return jsonify(stock)
    # return str(Next_ID)

@app.route("/Stocks", methods=["PUT"])
def update(id):
    sel_stock = list(filter(lambda s: s["id"] == id, stocks))
    if len(sel_stock) == 0:
        abort(400)

    sel_stock = sel_stock[0]
    if not request.json:
        abort(400)
    reqJSON = request.json

    if reqJSON["Stock"]:
        sel_stock["Stock"] = reqJSON["Stock"]
    if reqJSON["Price"]:
        sel_stock["Price"] = reqJSON["Price"]

    return jsonify(sel_stock)

@app.route("/Stocks", methods=["DELETE"])
def delete(id):
    return "in delete"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

If I run curl commands to get all the information or get the information by ID number, there is no issue. However, If I try the following curl command I get an error:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST -d "{\"Stock\":\"IBM\",\"Price\":\123}" http://127.0.0.1:5000/Stocks
```

> TypeError: create() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **do not** need to pass `id` to your POST method since its url does not have `id` as parameter:

```
@app.route("/Stocks", methods=["POST"])
def create(): # removed id
    """some code here"""
```

Comment: What exactly is changed in your suggestion?

Comment: @D Dhaliwal - thanks. Really stupid mistake that has been plaguing me for hours.

Comment: @marxmacher - he suggested I delete the "id" being passed into the function

Comment: Aaa, yes :) simple mistake